# Remote SSIS development

Tags: ssis, remote, development

I'm currently developing SSIS packages which include transferring data between two servers. The servers are in the same local LAN, but I'm remote to them.

Is there any way that I can develop the packages on my local workstation and get the advantages of the visual debugger, etc. while having the actual data processing only happen on my remote SSIS server, saving me from having the data transferred over the WAN and back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not.

Your options are

- install BIDS/SSDT and do the development on the server
- develop locally and pay the network penalty
- spin up local instances to negate the network penalty

I am a firm believer in the last option as it ensures my package development, pre 2012, used configuration to handle changing servers. If I deployed to Dev and it blew up, there was less stink eye directed my way vs Test when ZOMG, WE'VE BEEN WAITING ON THIS AND YOU'RE STILL MAKING CODING CHANGES!!!!

If it's a we don't allow data on developer machines, well it's a stupid rule and they need to either pony up for a tool like red gate's data generator or provide developers with a sane, safe, PII free backup they can use for local development purposes.

Comment: Thanks. What I was afraid of, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: If you develop locally, when you run from BIDDS/SSDT all paths will be from your local machine, not the server. How did you deal with this?